# Find LA workspace for an App Insights using Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I'd like to list all our Application Insights that have yet to be migrated to Workspace based AI using PowerShell. I can't seem to find the link between the workspace and an AI instance.

- Get-AzApplicationInsights has the AppInsights details but not a reference to the workspace
- Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace has the workspace details but no references to the linked AIs

Nor can I find a reference to it in the AppInsights API reference. Does anyone have any idea how to find the association between AI and a Log Analytics workspace this way?

Comment: I've managed to get the detail using Azure Resource Graph Explorer using a query like "resources
| where type == "microsoft.insights/components"
| project name, properties["IngestionMode"], properties["WorkspaceResourceId"]" but would still like to know how to do this via PwSh.

Comment: Don't I feel the fool. I neglected to update my Az module. After doing so, IngestionMode and WorkspaceId was available in the results.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce your scenario in my environment and got the results below:-***

I tried below command :-

```
Get-AzApplicationInsights -debug
```

And got workspaceID and IngestionMode set to Log analytics in the request body before I got the output like below :-

[image]

[image]

But the output of this command does not contain properties with WorkspaceId, Refer below :-

[image]

In order to check whether your Application Insight is connected to LA, You can call the  **Azure management API from Powershell and get the WorkspaceId or Ingestion**  type refer below :-

Code :-

```
 # We need to set the Authorization header first
 # We need to get a bearer token first
    
$AppId="<app-id"
$AppSecret="<app-secret>"
$TokenURI="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenanrt-id>/oauth2/token"
$Resource="https://management.core.windows.net/"
    
$BodyRequest="grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$AppId&client_secret=$AppSecret&resource=$Resource"
    
$AccessToken=Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $TokenURI `
    -Body $BodyRequest -ContentType  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    
# Now we can make the request to list all application insights
    
$RequestURI="https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/providers/Microsoft.Insights/components?api-version=2015-05-01"
    
$Headers=@{}
$Headers.Add("Authorization","Bearer " + $AccessToken.access_token) 
    
$ResourceRequest=Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $RequestURI -Headers $Headers
    
# Get application insights
    
$properties=$ResourceRequest.value.properties
```

Output :-

[image]

Using above method is easier than querying log analytics to get the connected application Insights, As

```
Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace -debug
```

does not call application insights in the API call refer debug below :-

[image]

You can only query Operations List which supports Application Insights via Log analytics like below :-
https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/operations?api-version=2021-12-01-preview

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some time passed by but as the topic becomes urgent now (deprecation on 29th February 2024) here's a way it works.

```
Get-AzApplicationInsights -SubscriptionId 'Your Subscription ID' | Format-Table -Property Name, IngestionMode, Id, @{label='Type';expression={
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.IngestionMode)) {
        'Unknown'
    } elseif ($_.IngestionMode -eq 'LogAnalytics') {
        'Workspace-based'
    } elseif ($_.IngestionMode -eq 'ApplicationInsights' -or $_.IngestionMode -eq 'ApplicationInsightsWithDiagnosticSettings') {
        'Classic'
    } else {
        'Unknown'
    }
}}
```

Additionally, you can add a loop to iterate over all your Azure subscriptions.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource#identifying-the-application-insights-resources-by-ingestion-type